# Override css variables from the angular library

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular library. I have a set of css variables for defining colours that applied to library components. They defined globally:

```
:root {
    -color-1: #000000;
    -color-2: #ffffff;
    ...
}
```

In app that uses this library I want to globally override some of these css variables in the same way. In styles.scss, for example I do:

```
:root {
    -color-1: #111111;
    -color-2: #cccccc;
}
```

but in result I get that css variables from the library have higher priority than css variables from my app, because css from my app included as external file using <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">, but styles from library included as internal css using <style> tag in <head> section.

If I add !important to css variables in my app:

```
:root {
    -color-1: #111111 !important;
    -color-2: #cccccc !important;
}
```

everything works as expected but I want to find another way, because !important is not the best approach.

Comment: Did you try to include your CSS after the Lib?

Comment: What library are you using? Customizing colors is a pretty standard feature for an UI library, maybe the documentation tells you how.

Comment: Is this really your CSS code? [MDN docs - CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#using_a_prefix_of_two_dashes_--) show to use two dashes `--` to prefix a CSS variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you can take to override CSS variables from an Angular library without using !important is by utilizing CSS specificity.

1. Wrap your application in a container with a specific class or ID
2. Use that container to increase the specificity of your CSS selectors

Something like this

```
<div class="my-app">
  <!-- your code-->
</div>
```

```
.my-app {
  --color-1: #111111;
  --color-2: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: Even you can use `app-root{--color-1:#1111;--color2:#ccc}` if the selector of your main app is app-root

Comment: Yes, I tried the exact same thing before. The only thing is that with this and Ted's approaches I can't set the overridden variable for the body because it is outside the app-root scope.